# Ionic Capacitor Module Not Found

Tags: angular, android-studio, ionic-framework, capacitor, capacitor-plugin

I'm getting the following error on code that was working fine a few days ago.  Something in the dev environment changed and I'm unable to determine what is missing.

This is a Windows 11 environment with a fresh Android Studio install, SDK

```
> ionic cap sync

./src/app/pages/tabs/tabs.page.ts:5:0-45 - Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@capacitor/browser' in 'workspace\app\src\app\pages\tabs'
```

I've run the following successfully

```
> npm install @capacitor/browser

up to date, audited 1274 packages in 2s

168 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities
```

and

```
> npm update

up to date, audited 1274 packages in 24s

168 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities
```

The two lines concerning the browser API are the following (taken from official examples):

```
import { Browser } from '@capacitor/browser';

async loadExternalURL(targetUrl){
  await Browser.open({ url: targetUrl });
}
```

If I comment out the usage line then the build is successful and the app runs fine.

```
async loadExternalURL(targetUrl){
  // await Browser.open({ url: targetUrl });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Of course I found the solution right after giving up and posting it on StackOverflow...

I don't know WHY it worked, but I deleted `node_modules` and `package-lock.json` and then ran `npm install` and `npx cap sync`.

Now everything is building fine!

Comment: Thanks for this - this got me out of a similar error trying to get capacitor working for a new/migrating app.